# jQuery grabbing header results in empty content

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I know this sounds weird. But I'm using the jQuery Cycle plugin with a WordPress site to pull in a custom post type as a banner image with content. For the pagination, I want the post title to be the link text, rather than your standard "1 2 3 4..." etc.

I managed to figure out how to do it - but now I have a fun new issue.  <del>When I pull the post title and pop it into the pagination link, my post content disappears.  It would seem jQuery is grabbing what it finds, *removes it*, and pops the items it's looking for in the link button. Which is weird.</del>

Anyway, would anyone know how to fix this? This is my jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            $('#slideshow div.slide:first').fadeIn(1000, function() {
                $('#slideshow').after('<div id="pagination"><div id="page_inner"><ul>').cycle({
                    fx: 'scrollHorz',
                    speed: 500,
                    timeout: 0,
                    pager: '#pagination #page_inner ul',
                    pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { 
                        $('.slide_caption', slide).children('h3');
                        //alert($(slide).text());
                        return '<li><a href="#">' + $(slide).text() + '</a></li>';
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Basically, I want the jQuery to look in the slide_caption div, find the first `<h3>` tag and copy that text and pop it in for the link button text. It's finding it <del>and doing it with the above code - but it's also stripping out all of the content in the slide_content div while doing so.</del> and now it's pulling in the entire content of the post into the button, instead of just the `<h3>` tag.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you :)

Comment: Should $('slide_caption', slide) not be $('#slide_caption', slide) or $('.slide_caption', slide) instead?

Comment: Excellent point, Gordon.  I also found another mistake in the code I popped in above - that's code I was messing with - whoops.  ...and there. Figured out how to edit and put in the proper code.  Thank you!

Comment: Okay, I've made a little bit of progress. I'm editing the original code up there to show the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're not grabbing the H3's `text()` and are instead pulling the entire `text()` from your slide.

```
pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { 
    return '<li><a href="#">' + $(slide).find('.slide_caption h3').text() + '</a></li>';
}
```

versus

```
pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { 
    $('.slide_caption', slide).children('h3'); // You're not doing anything with this
    //alert($(slide).text());
    // $(slide).text() => complete text from your slide parameter
    return '<li><a href="#">' + $(slide).text() + '</a></li>';
}
```

Comment: You, sir, are my hero. I could kiss you. May good luck be with you for the rest of your life!